# Best practice for incorporating catkin into larger CMake project?

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to incorporate a few catkin-based ROS groovy packages into a larger CMake project that does not use ROS or catkin.

Catkin requires that the top-level directory from which you invoke catkin_make (e.g. the catkin workspace) does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

I have a conceptual out a hack to invoke the catkin_make from above without including a CMakeLists.txt in the workspace, and use an external variable definition to pass information into catkin_make, but would assume others have better solutions.

Can anyone share any best practices for incorporating ROS into larger non-ROS projects?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61774/best-practice-for-incorporating-catkin-into-larger-cmake-project?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2013-05-17**:
I get a "famous question" badge, but no answers/discussion.  Looks like I'll have to do my hack.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-17**:
I guess so. When no one responds it's generally because no one knows the answer.

**Comment by [hauptmech](https://answers.ros.org/users/1829/hauptmech/) on 2015-11-26**:
ROS brings a similar amount of baggage to cmake as qt does. Not much but more than I'd like. Integrating ros code into an existing cmake project is straightforward. The catkin [CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) guide will tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best practice would be to build the ROS stuff in a `catkin` workspace and then `make install` those packages separate from your other project and then build your project on top of the installed `catkin` packages, which can be found using `find_package` or `pkg-config`.

The other good thing to do would be to just use `catkin` for all of your project, so that your "larger" project is just another package in the `catkin` workspace, this is the best way to get access (`find_package`) to all of the packages in the `catkin` workspace at build time in a single CMake invocation, and this is what `catkin` was designed to do.

If you are dead set on integrating several `catkin` packages in to a single CMake project, another strategy might be to just have a `catkin` workspace in your project and call `add_subdirectory` on the `catkin` workspace. I haven't tried this and I am not sure what side effects this might have, but you are welcome to try it.

Either way I would not call `catkin_make` directly from another CMake project. All `catkin_make` does is something like this:

```
# In catkin workspace with packages in the `src` folder
cd src
catkin_init_workspace # This creates the CMakeLists.txt in the top of the workspace
cd ..
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../src -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install -DCATKIN_DEVEL_SPACE=../devel
make
```

There is no magic in `catkin_make` which is required to build a `catkin` workspace. You should be able to copy over the `top-level.cmake` file to the `catkin` workspace in your project and use `add_subdirectory` on it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3